# Profiling Implementation Issue with GCC C/C++ cross for PowerPC

Tags: c, gcc, profiling, powerpc, ecos

I'm trying to get the gcc profiling implemented.

I am using the embedded environment eCos with a PowerPC. I programming in C.

When I compile and link using the `-pg` switch, I find that the symbol `_mcount` is undefined.

I realize I need to implement this function as it is target specific.

What are the requirements for the `_mcount` function?

Am I correct that it must save and restore all registers? Are there any special registers that have to be saved and restored along with the standard 32?

I have seen commments stating that `_mcount` must be called with interrupts disabled, or does `_mcount` disable interrupts before recorded the call tree data?

My PowerPC is an 8245. This is a 603e family processor.

I am using GCC 4.6.1 built as a cross-compiler as powerpc-eabi.

Here's an example of the _mcount call generate by gcc. The first instruction of the function being profiled is the first line shown:

```
100b40:       7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
100b44:       3d 80 00 23     lis     r12,35
100b48:       90 01 00 04     stw     r0,4(r1)
100b4c:       38 0c 82 a8     addi    r0,r12,-32088
100b50:       48 05 19 25     bl      152474 <_mcount>
100b54:       94 21 ff 88     stwu    r1,-120(r1)
100b58:       7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
100b5c:       90 01 00 7c     stw     r0,124(r1)
100b60:       93 e1 00 74     stw     r31,116(r1)
100b64:       7c 3f 0b 78     mr      r31,r1
```

The code created by the compiler switch `-pg` performs the following.

- 1) The address of the caller is stored on the stack with two instruction `mflr r0` and `stw r0,4(r1)`.
- 2) The address of the function just entered is stored in `r0` with the two instructions `lis r12,35` and `addi r0,r12,-32088`.

Thus when `_mcount` is called `r0` contains the entered function address, `4(r1)` contains the program counter of the caller. This pair of information is stored and used to create the call graph.

This information I found by reading the gcc source, gcc/libffi/src/powerpc/asm.h.

I'm still unsure what `_mcount` is expected to return. It appears it has to restore LR, so that `_mcount` can't use `blr`, it has to restore LR from `(4)r1` and use a jump instruction instead of `blr` to return to the instruction after `bl _mcount`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you're [*implementing gprof*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Comment: Isn't gprof the tool that looks that the results stored by _mcount and the profile timer? _mcount is the function called while the program is executing. gprof is what retrieves and displays this information. Have I stated the separation of functionality correctly?

Comment: Yeah, *gprof* needs a function that, when a function B is entered, increments a counter saying which function A called B. That may be what you've got to do, but there are much better ways (than *gprof*) for programmers to find opportunities for optimization.

Comment: I have the function that holds the incremented values. What I seem to have to do is write the bridge function, mcount, that takes in the caller and callee data in two locations, map these values to the form required by the storage function and return to the caller of mcount having restored registers, especially LR.         Regarding other methods of instrumentation, I'm working with an embedded OS, gprof is only supported method.

Comment: Sorry then. *gprof* is good for giving you piles of numbers and leaving you scratching your head. When I worked on embedded software, I just took stackshots using an in-circuit-emulator. It's not for sissies, but it never failed.

Answer (score 1):

There's an implementation of `_mcount` for PowerPC now checked-in to the eCos RTOS repository:

http://ecos.sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ecos/packages/hal/powerpc/arch/current/src/mcount.S?cvsroot=ecos

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but the assembly code below will create a dummy _mcount for PowerPC.

The code can be used to resolve the `_mcount` external, but no call graph data is recorded.
This code was suggested by the gcc file `\gcc\testsuite\gcc.target\powerpc\ppc-abi-2.c`, function `my_mcount()`

```
    .text                
    .globl  _mcount
_mcount:
    # Move LR to CTR and return via CTR
    mflr r0
    mtctr r0
    lwz r0,4(r1)
    mtlr r0
    bctr
```